# How to make jQuery only select the FIRST closest() element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<h5>Do you have a reference number?</h5>
  <span class="form-mini-style has_sub_span_field"> <input type="radio" value="1" name="ref">Yes </span>
  <span class="form-mini-style has_sub_span_field"> <input type="radio" value="0" name="ref">no </span> </span>
  <span class="sub_span" style="display:none;">
    <h5>Reference Number:</h5> --- FIELD HERE --- </span>

<h5>Other questions . . . 1 </h5>
  <span class="form-mini-style"> <input type="radio" value="1" name="oq1">Yes </span>
  <span class="form-mini-style"> <input type="radio" value="0" name="oq1">no </span> </span>
  <!-- no sub_span -->

<h5>Other questions . . . 2 </h5>
  <span class="form-mini-style"> <input type="radio" value="1" name="oq2">Yes </span>
  <span class="form-mini-style"> <input type="radio" value="0" name="oq2">no </span> </span>    
  <!-- no sub_span -->

<h5>Do you like TacoBell?</h5>
  <span class="form-mini-style has_sub_span_field"> <input type="radio" value="1" name="tacobell">Yes </span>
  <span class="form-mini-style has_sub_span_field"> <input type="radio" value="0" name="tacobell">no </span> </span>
  <span class="sub_span" style="display:none;">
    <h5>Taco Bell Favorite Foods:</h5> --- FIELD HERE --- </span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
  $("input", ".has_sub_span_field").on('click', function () {
  var next_span_class, next_span_value;
    next_span_class = $(this).parent().next().attr('class');
    next_span_value = $(this).val();

    if (next_span_class != 'sub_span') {
      next_span_class = $(this).parent().next().next().attr('class');
    }

    if (next_span_class == 'sub_span' && next_span_value == 1) {
      $('.' + next_span_class).is(":visible") ? true : $('.' + next_span_class).show();
    } else {
      $('.' + next_span_class).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

**What I want to do is only `show` the `sub_span` for which is `closest` to the radio input selected.** Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ea6AK/

Problem with the above code is that **all** `sub_span` are shown when a radio button is clicked regardless of proximity to the radio button clicked.

Comment: Because an element has at most one immediate parent, `.closest()` already does what you describe; there is at most one "closest" element. However, you're not using `.closest()` at all. So: what does the title have to do with the question body?

Comment: @Matt because I'm not exactly sure how to use the `closest()` method. Because if I do `next_span_class = $(this).closest('.sub_span');` I don't get anything back.

Comment: That's because that's not what `.closest()` does...

Comment: Looks like I should be using `.nextUntil()`. Sound right?

Comment: That would be one way to do it, yes - you could use `.nextUntil('.sub_span').next()` (because `.nextUntil()` stops just short)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code selects elements by class:

```
$('.' + next_span_class)
```

So that's exactly what you'll get. Why go through all that indirection when you can simply traverse the DOM and "walk" directly to the element you want to show/hide?

```
$(function () {
    $("input", ".has_sub_span_field").on('click', function () {
        var next_span = $(this).parent().nextAll(".sub_span:first");
        var next_span_value = $(this).val();

        if (next_span_value == 1) {
            next_span.show();
        } else {
            next_span.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/PgrAy/

---

N.B. instead of letting `==` perform type coercion for you, it's better style to write this:

```
if (parseInt(next_span_value, 10) === 1) {
    ...
}
```

---

> Why `nextAll()` and not `nextUntil()`?

`nextUntil()` isn't idea because it selects multiple elements, and it stops short of the element that you actually want. Read the docs carefully:

> *Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.*

---

> Why do you have to explicitly say `parent()` shouldn't it be smart enough to just walk the dom until a match is found?

There's no magic here. jQuery doesn't know where in the DOM, in relation to the starting element, you want to search. So you have to be explicit.

Comment: Right. now I'm realizing my mistake: `$('.' + next_span_class).is(":visible") ? true : $('.' + next_span_class).show();`. But how do you "walk through" elements?

Comment: Why `nextAll()` and not `nextUntil()` ? And Why do you have to explicitly say `parent()` shouldn't it be smart enough to just walk the dom *until* a match is found?

Comment: `if (parseInt(next_span_value, 10) === 1) {` Why is this a better style? What's the `10` represent? *bits*?

Comment: I'm not going to spoon-feed this to you. Read some docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: I see that's why you call `next()` after the `nextUntil()` because it stop right before the selector. Trying to think in what case that would be used.

Comment: You'd use it in whatever case you want those particular elements. Yes, that's a tautology. Just like you'd use `.next()` when... you want the next element.

Comment: Hey Matt your answer is great. +1 and check. Very thorough. You should spoon feed. It's good for the soul. It builds character and humility. Besides one day you might need someone to spoon feed you. :) Hey thanks again.

Comment: "There's no magic here. jQuery doesn't know where in the DOM, in relation to the starting element, you want to search. So you have to be explicit." Doesn't the point of click give it a starting point? Why need to be more explicit than this?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48789/discussion-between-matt-ball-and-feed-me-code)